# Which one would be better, multiprocessing or sub processing for this ping script

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, ping

So for work, I was asked to recreate a ping script that we were using to check on machines. The old one was written in Perl, and I am more comfortable with Python, so I wrote a ping script in Python. I was looking over some of the differences between multiprocessing and subprocesses, and I think multiprocessing would work better, since we have a lot of host names, I think it would be better to use multiple threads, each to ping a set number of host names. But I couldn't quite follow the multiprocessing guides since I was needing to use subprocesses to quiet the console output. My question is how would I go about using multi-threading if I am also using subprocesses?

My working code is as follows:

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
import re


hostfile = open("hosts.txt", "r")
lines = hostfile.readlines()

#Create an output file to write output to
with open('Ping_Results.txt', 'a') as f:
   
   
    #Append the current day to the end of the recently opened file
    today = datetime.now()
    dateStr = str(today)
    appendDate = "\n------------------------------------" + " " + dateStr + " " + "-----------------------------------\n"
    f.write(appendDate)

    for i in lines:
        #Ping each device on hostfile with 1 packet with size of 10 bytes. 
        #shell=True to enable multiple arguments for the ping command. capture_output is to capture the output, and text=True. 
        p1 = subprocess.run(['ping' ,'-n', '1', '-l', '10', i], shell= True, capture_output=True)
    
        #Error checking for host unreachable vs host does not exist. Bit buggy
        l = p1.stdout.decode()
        unreach = re.search(r'Destination host unreachable', l)
        
        if unreach:
            status = i.rstrip() + " was not reachable"
            unreachable = (p1.stdout.decode())
            f.write(unreachable)
            #print(status) 
        elif ( p1.returncode ==0 ):
            #if host is able to be pinged and is responsive.
            status = i.rstrip() + " was reachable"
            reachable=(p1.stdout.decode())
            f.write(reachable)
            print(status)
            print(reachable)
       
        else:   
            #If host is not reachable. 
            status = i.rstrip() + " was not found. Check logs for more information"

            #Decode the string to get the readable console output infomation. 
            notFound= (p1.stdout.decode())

            #Writes to the Ping_Results file.
            f.write(notFound)
            #print(status)`
```

This works fine, but it is a lot slower when I have 10-20 hostnames. I tried splitting up the sub-processes, but I couldn't figure it out. I kept finding examples of people using
 `p1 = subprocess.run(['ping' ,'-n', '1', '-l', '10', i], shell= True, capture_output=True)`
and that does work, and I like how it works, but I need a way to speed it up to be able to handle 200+ hosts. Any links to the proper guides would be appreciated or any clarity on the topic in general. Thank you.

I have tried various multiprocessing guides, but I was wanting to quiet the console output, and subprocesses were the only way that I had found that worked with how I had it set up. I may be misunderstanding exactly how subprocesses work. In my mind, each sub-process acts like a thread, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `subprocess` to run the external ping command. As for running multiple pings in parallel, the `multiprocessing` module implements and thread and processes using very similar interfaces to make them easy to interchange. Since you code is mostly I/O bound and the `ping` is already being done in a separate process, a thread pool would be a good choice. You pick a size for the pool and let it figure out the details of how to make the threads run.

Put all of the ping code in a function that returns a result instead of writing the file. Have the pool use that function to map your input data to the ping output, then write that to a file.

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
import re
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.pool

def ping_host(host):
    #Ping each device on hostfile with 1 packet with size of 10 bytes. 
    #shell=True to enable multiple arguments for the ping command. capture_output is to capture the output, and text=True. 
    p1 = subprocess.run(['ping' ,'-n', '1', '-l', '10', i], shell= True, capture_output=True)

    #Error checking for host unreachable vs host does not exist. Bit buggy
    l = p1.stdout.decode()
    unreach = re.search(r'Destination host unreachable', l)
    
    if unreach:
        status = i.rstrip() + " was not reachable"
        unreachable = (p1.stdout.decode())
        return unreachable

    if ( p1.returncode ==0 ):
        #if host is able to be pinged and is responsive.
        status = i.rstrip() + " was reachable"
        reachable=(p1.stdout.decode())
        print(f"{status}\n{reachable}")
        return reachable
    
    #If host is not reachable. 
    status = i.rstrip() + " was not found. Check logs for more information"

    #Decode the string to get the readable console output infomation. 
    notFound= (p1.stdout.decode())

    #Writes to the Ping_Results file.
    #print(status)`
    return notFound



hostfile = open("hosts.txt", "r")
lines = hostfile.readlines()

#Create an output file to write output to
with open('Ping_Results.txt', 'a') as f:
    #Append the current day to the end of the recently opened file
    today = datetime.now()
    dateStr = str(today)
    appendDate = "\n------------------------------------" + " " + dateStr + " " + "-----------------------------------\n"
    f.write(appendDate)

    with mp.pool.ThreadPool(min(len(lines), 20)) as pool:
        hostfile.writelines(pool.map(ping_host, lines))
```